# Is「羨む価値のないもの」grammatical / natural?

Tags: grammar

I saw a post on HelloTalk from a Japanese person mentioning how he would like to just get a job by being the boss's son or something, and I started thinking how to say, **"It's not a thing (i.e. life situation) worth being envious for"**

My current version is in the title, so, I would phrase it something like,「それは、羨む価値のないものだと思います。」For my "extrapolation" I used this example from Jisho:

> ある時代の最も洗練された審美眼によって美しいと考えられたものが美術館にはたくさんあるのだが、それは今の私たちには**価値のないもの**に見えるのである。

I assume we could use こと as well, but it feels that in this case, it's about feelings, so もの is more appropriate (my understanding of the 使い分け of こと/もの is still fuzzy, though)

So, my question is basically this: **is my version grammatical/natural and does it convey the idea of "not worth being envious for" well?** What could be better options, including maybe the more colloquial expressions?

Comment: Yes (but こと might be better unless the word he used to mention it is semantically incompatible with it)

Comment: @broccolifacemask, thank you for the answer. That's the thing: I don't know much about compatibility. He basically just posted a (fake?) review from a presumed job search site where a certain guy was bragging about how the interview went "chill" because his dad knew the interviewer (or was the boss of the company). So, the Japanese person who posted it wrote, "Wish my life was that easy". That's it